# Add computed specified decimal column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a computed decimal column in SQL that calculates an order total in currency format (2 decimal places). The intended precision would be 8, and scale 2.

My formula would be

```
[quantity] * ([list_price] - ([list_price] * [discount]))
```

The problem I have is that the precision ends up being 27 and scale 4. I'm unable to edit this in the column properties.

Can this be changed somehow? Or is there another way to add a computed decimal column that would allow me to keep my specified precision and scale?

Comment: `cast(quantity * (list_price - (list_price * discount)) as decimal(8,2))` ?

Comment: If only there was a way to use `list_price` just once in this completed mathematical expression...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 CONVERT( DECIMAL(8,2),([quantity] * ([list_price] - ([list_price] * [discount]))) ) AS decimal_value
```

OR

```
CAST( ([quantity] * ([list_price] - ([list_price] * [discount]))) AS DECIMAL(8,2) ) AS decimal_value
```